# Can I runtime.exec() a 32-bit batch file from 64-bit Java?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, batch-file, 32bit-64bit

We're in the process of upgrading our server from 32-bit Windows 2003 to 64-bit Windows 2008, and I'm doing some due diligence before we select 32-bit vs 64-bit versions of our upgraded server applications.

We currently have a Tomcat server with a number of web applications that launch perl scripts (inside of Windows batch files) using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.  The perl scripts, in turn, launch MS Office to create and manipulate objects.

From what I've read, most people (including Microsoft) recommend installing the 32-bit Office, unless you have a very good reason to install the 64-bit version (and at this point, I don't think we do).

It looks like that probably means that I have to be running 32-bit Perl in order to create the 32-bit Office objects.

The question is, does that also mean I need to be running Tomcat on 32-bit Java?  If so, I have a second question, which is whether I can install multiple Tomcat instances in different JVMs, in order to take advantage of the additional memory in the 64-bit OS?

If it is possible to launch a 32-bit process from within 64-bit Java, are there any special tricks, or is it enough to just specify WOW64 in the path to the cmd command?

Comment: you can launch a 32 bit process in a 64 bit environment, but as you mentioned you might not be able to use the additional memory, you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to run a 32bit or a 64 bit application, a 32 bit process in 64bit windows will have a *32 against its name in the task manager..

Comment: You don't necessarily need to be running 32-bit Perl.  I would expect that 64-bit Perl would be able to manipulate the 32-bit version of Office perfectly well, probably without even needing to make any changes to the code.

Comment: Harry, that is one of the things I'm trying to find out.  I have seen posts of people who had trouble and whose problems were resolved when they uninstalled 64-bit Perl and installed 32-bit instead.  If we can manage to get everything working in 64-bit that is probably preferable going forward, which is why I was asking about launching 32-bit processes from within 64-bit java (that is, I'd like to run 64-bit Java if at all possible, even if I can't run 64-bit Office or 64-bit Perl).

Comment: Thanks, Anantha.  My primary concern is not memory limits on the individual batch file/perl scripts, but the fact that Tomcat will be running several of these simultaneously, so their aggregate memory usage could go over the 32-bit limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [exec docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) state

> (...) Starting an operating system process is highly system-dependent. (...)

As such, one would assume that it is totally possible to start a 32 bit process from a 64 bit Java process, as starting another process on Windows doesn't care about the bitness at all.

If you start the `SysWOW64\cmd.exe` you should be completely fine.

Which Perl distribution are you running? The [Strawberry Portable ZIP editions](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html) can be used side-by-side without installing anything.

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  We are currently using ActivePerl 5.8.8.  I'm also trying to decide whether to upgrade to a more current release, but that's a question for another thread.  :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was stuck on `ASP 5.8.8` too, converting to strawberry 5.10 was pretty trivial in my case (but I haven't converted all). Good thing is, even with ASP 5.8 installed, you can still use a Strawberry portable edition, as all perl depends on are the correct path settings, and these are trivially fixed for a portable launcher script.